# Как кастомизировать jquery?

Tags: jquery

Что если мне нужен не весь JQuery а только AJAX-запросы из него? Или какие-то другие функции на выбор. Можно ли эту библиотеку сначала кастомизировать а потом скачать выбранные компоненты как в bootstrap?

Comment: возьмите `zepto` он более легкий.

Comment: Если поискать в интернете, то находится такое: https://jquery.com/download/#build-from-git http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/